# Blender 2.79a X.files

Tags: import

Is there an .X file importer for 2.79 versions of Blender. From what I seen, the only .X file importer I could find doesn't work. 
 Would I need to get an older version of Blender to use the .X file and import the addon or is there another way to use the 2.79 version with .X files.

https://github.com/Littleneo/Directx_Blender/wiki works with older versions of blender, I am going to try some things to see if it can work with 2.79

Comment: Since you don't even tell us which add-on you're using, I would suggest contacting the add-on's author instead. They should know which version of Blender is supported, and how to use it.

Comment: The only addon I found for .X files was for 2.6 and I seen a forum post linking it to 2.7, which is Littleneo's DirectX importer. The question was is there an importer for 2.79 versions of blender, if there isn't, then I can already get an older version of blender. I am reading this forum that is one of the more recent posts on the same importer, but they are mainly talking about the exporter.

Comment: limemidolin and I did some more work on this issue by forking littleneo's version (he isn't available or isn't accepting pull requests). It technically works with 2.79 now but I can't get most files to import. Assist if possible: github.com/poikilos/io_import_x